# Ubuntu dont start ( Windows 10 already installed)

Tags: system

hope you can help me with this. I wanted to try ubuntu on my ACER laptop which already have windows10 . I have installed ubuntu with usb live cd with its partitions ( before i have reduced the size of my hard disk to install ubuntu there). I have installed ubuntu with no problems but when the installation finished and i restart the laptop it goes straigh to windows and i cant see the screen that allows me to select which o.s i want to use.

I would apreciate any tip of you could give to run ubuntu .

Thank you very much and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to boot into Ubuntu,you will need to **turn off the fast boot** option.

Here's how you can do it:

- click on the *Control Panel* in you Windows 10 setting option that appears.
- When the *Control Panel* appears click on the *System and Security*.
- Now click on *Power Options*.
- On the following screen click on *Choose what the power button does*.
- A screen will appear with the heading *Define power buttons and turn on 
  password protection*.
- Scroll down until you see *Shutdown Settings*.
- An option should be available called *Turn on fast startup (recommended)*.
- Uncheck this option.
- Click *Save Changes*.
- after saving the changes you made,restart the system. The system will ask on boot weather you want to boot into Ubuntu or Windows or whichever OS you are using.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your answer, i already did that and it didn´t work. :c

I dont know what´s going on :c